# docker-compose up gives error: bash: sails: command not found

Tags: docker, sails.js, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file with the following content:

```
version: '2'

services:
 MongoDB:
   image: mongo

 Parrot-API:
   build: ./Parrot-API
   image: sails-js:dev
   volumes:
    - "/user/Code/node/Parrot-API:/host"
   command: bash -c "cd /host && sails lift"
   links:
    - MongoDB:MongoDB
   ports:
    - "3050:1337"
```

The file basically runs two containers: mongodb and web app (in directory `./Parrot-API`) built in sails.js. However, when I run `docker-compose up` in the terminal, I got this error: **Parrot-API_1  | bash: sails: command not found
node_Parrot-API_1 exited with code 127**. Note that `sails.js` is a node.js web framework, and `sails lift` starts the app at port 1337.

I have done some google search and have found some similar questions, but not helpful in my case.

btw, I have the following `Dockerfile` in the Parrot-API folder:

```
FROM sails-js:dev
VOLUME /host
WORKDIR /host
RUN rm -rf node_modules && \
        echo "hello world!" && \
        pwd && \
        ls -lrah
EXPOSE 1337
CMD npm install -g sails && npm install && sails lift
```

**The file structure is following:**

```
|- docker-compose.yml
|- Parrot-API/Dockerfile
|- Parrot-API/app.js, etc..
```

It is clear to me that the `Parrot-API` docker container exits immediately due to the reason that `sails lift` command is not executed, but how to make the container work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You showed a docker-compose.yml that builds a sails-js:dev image, and you showed a Dockerfile that is based on the sails-js:dev image. This appears to be recursive.

Your Dockerfile itself ends with a CMD in lieu of an ENTRYPOINT that does the npm install of sails. Since you did this as a CMD instead of a RUN, sails is not installed in your image, the install is launched on a container run, but only if you don't run the container with any arguments of your own, like you are doing in the docker-compose.yml with a custom command.

The fix is to update the Dockerfile with a proper base image and change the CMD to a RUN. I'm also seeing a few other mistakes like creating a volume and then modifying the contents, where volumes ignore other changes after they have been created. The `FROM node` is just a guess based on your npm commands, feel free to adjust:

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir -p /host && cd /host && npm install -g sails && npm install
EXPOSE 1337
WORKDIR /host
VOLUME /host
CMD sails lift
```